# Equivalence classes in the logical equivalence on some finite set of propositional formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, equivalence-relations

I'm having trouble understanding the following problem:

> Let $S_n$ be the set of all formulas that can be built up with the
>   atoms $\{A_1,...,A_n\}$. How many equivalence classes does the
>   logical equivalence $\equiv$ on the set $S_n$ have?

I know what an equivalence relation and equivalence classes are. However, I can't figure out what 'a logical equivalence on a set of propositional formulas' means.

Does it mean that some formulas $F$ and $G$ from $S_n$ are logically equivalent, that is $F\equiv G$? Then how can we count the number of equivalence classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Your last paragraph suggests that you do have the right idea about what is wanted. Two propositional formulas are logically equivalent if and only if they have the same truth table. How many different truth tables are possible for a set of $n$ atoms? Each one will represent a whole equivalence class of logically equivalent formulas.

Comment: I know that if there are $n$ atoms, we have $2^n$ possible interpretations. But how many formulas can be constructed from $n$ atoms? Maybe, I'm thinking in the wrong direction. But we have $F = A_1 \wedge A_2 \equiv G = A_2 \wedge A_1$ and $F = A_1 \Rightarrow A_2 \not\equiv G = A_2 \Rightarrow A_1$. How do we know how many equivalent formulas can be built up?

Comment: @stillenat: Infinitely many different formulas are possible. For example, $A_1,A_1\land A_1,A_1\land A_1\land A_1,\ldots$ are all different formulas. But that doesn’t matter: we’re counting equivalence classes of formulas, not the formulas themselves. All of the infinitely many formulas that I just listed are logically equivalent, so they belong to a single equivalence class.

Comment: Does it mean we also have $n$ equivalence classes? How can I prove it mathematically?

Comment: @stillenat: Quite a bit more than $n$. There are $2^n$ possible assignments of truth values fo the $n$ atoms. If $\varphi$ is a propositional formula, it must have a truth value for each of those $2^n$ assignments. There are $2$ choices for each of those $2^n$ assignments (i.e., for each of the $2^n$ rows of a truth table for $\varphi$). In how many different ways can we make those choices? You could also look at it this way: each formula $\varphi$ is a function from $n$-tuples of truth values to truth values. For instance, if $n=2$, the formula $A_1\lor A_2$ takes the pairs ...

Comment: ... $\langle T,T\rangle,\langle T,F\rangle$, and $\langle F,T\rangle$ to $T$ and the pair $\langle F,F\rangle$ to $F$. The domain of this function is the set of all $2^n$ $n$-tuples of truth values, one for each possible interpretation. The range is the $2$-element set $\{T,F\}$. Two formulas are logically equivalent if the correspond to the same function. How many such functions are there?

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it. If we have $2$ atoms $A_1$ and $A_2$, there are 8 different possible outcomes that some formula can produce. So we have 8 distinct equivalence classes, namely $[TTTT]$, $[TTTF]$, $[TTFT]$, $[TFTT]$, $[FTTT]$, $[FFTT]$, $[FFFT]$, $[FFFF]$. In other words, $2\cdot2^2 = 2^{2+1} = 2^3$ So for $n$ atoms, we have $2^{n+1}$ equivalence classes. Is this correct?

Comment: @stillenat: Not quite. For two atoms there are $4$ interpretations. Each can give a formula one of the $2$ truth values. Filling in the truth table for the formula requires making a $2$-way choice $4$ times, for a total of $2^4=16$ equivalence classes, not $2\cdot 4=8$. Can you fix the general case now?

Comment: Oh, so it should be $2^{2^n}$?

Comment: @stillenat: There you go! Yes: there are $2^{2^n}$ functions from the set of $2^n$ interpretations to the set $\{T,F\}$ of truth values. Each formula determines one of these truth functions, and formulas are logically equivalent if and only if they determine the same truth function, so there are $2^{2^n}$ equivalence classes of formulas.

Comment: I see now. That was quite difficult for me to comprehend. I really appreciate your time and explanation.

Comment: @stillenat: My pleasure: I’m glad that it helped.